# what is the difference between Pancajanya , Devadatta and Paundram?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

> pāñchajanyaṁ hṛiṣhīkeśho devadattaṁ dhanañjayaḥ

> pauṇḍraṁ dadhmau mahā-śhaṅkhaṁ bhīma-karmā vṛikodaraḥ

> Then, Lord Krsna blew His conchshell, called Pancajanya; Arjuna blew his, the Devadatta; and Bhima, the voracious eater and performer of Herculean tasks, blew his terrific conchshell called Paundram.

what  is the difference  between Pancajanya , Devadatta and Paundram?

Comment: What's the difference between the  vehicle in my home and that in your home? The difference is of the owner. That's all.

Comment: They are simply conchshells. Their differences are not mentioned in the scriptures.

Comment: oks  thanks u @TheCrimsonUniverse